# VOIP Services not working in Production environment, but working fine in test server

Tags: certificate, apple-push-notifications, voip, amazon-sns, production-environment

I am using **APNS Certificate & VOIP Services Certificate in parallel** in my **iOS apps**, I have created **APNS (both Sandbox & Production)**, then uses **AWS SNS** as an intermediate and then creates application ARN and endpoints at **SNS** and send push from my server via SNS (with the corresponding certificates), these steps work fine for APNS, Push notifications are working fine.

But when I go to **VOIP**, I am able to get the app working fine in my test server (that is **I am getting VOIP notification when using test server**), **but in case of production, it's not working**...

**FYI**

- Am using two **different tokens for both APNS & VOIP**
- Have created & rechecked the VOIP certificates(single certificate for both test & production)

Am not getting any idea of whats wrong... TIA... Requesting for suggestions or anyone faced the same issue?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you did everything correct.

What I can recommend as an alternative solution is to create a **single Universal APNS certificate** which works everywhere - for Production/Sandbox standard pushes + VoIP Production/Sandbox

And use this single certificate for both cases

Here is a very simple guide I used to generate single Universal certificate which works everywhere https://developers.connectycube.com/ios/how-to-create-apns-certificate

Comment: Did you mean this works for VOIP Also? how to differ it for VOIP and normal APN's?

Answer (score 0):

You have to check the endpoint for the APNS. So when you are working in dev environment you should send in `APNS_ENDPOINT: api.development.push.apple.com` and when in production in `APNS_ENDPOINT: api.push.apple.com`